# Attaching a process to a terminal in LInux

Tags: linux

I have a file opened in `vi` running in a terminal(`xterm`), if I directly closes the terminal without first closing the file then I can see the `vi` still running in the background(`ps x`). Now is there any way to attach that process i.e. vi to some other terminal so that I can continue my work on the file. I have also tried `fd` command but it fails.

Comment: `vi &` detachs the process from the existing terminal

Comment: what if due to some other reasons my terminal get killed?

Comment: @Ravi it would be in a different process. So it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible “cleanly”. There are tools such as [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) and [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) that create a remanent virtual terminal: you can start your program inside screen, detach the screen session, and later reattach the screen session on a different terminal. But that requires planning ahead.

It is possible to use [ptrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace) to fiddle with the process's file descriptors to reconnect them to another terminal. That doesn't work reliably because it might create inconsistencies in the process's data structures: some programs won't mind, others will crash. You can do this by attaching the program in a debugger and issue the right sequence of system calls (at least `open`, `dup` and `close` for each of standard input, standard output and standard error). There are several existing tools that can do this, for example [neercs](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/neercs) and [retty](http://pasky.or.cz/~pasky/dev/retty/).

See also [How can I pause up a running process over ssh, disown it, associate it to a new screen shell and unpause it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4034/885), [View Script Over SSH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4786/885), [Can I nohup/screen an already-started process?](https://serverfault.com/q/24425/48279), [Resume command running in dropped SSH session](https://serverfault.com/q/115998/48279).

Answer (score 1):

You can try [GNU screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). It is made for this purpose.

> Screen is a full-screen window manager that multiplexes a physical terminal between several processes, typically interactive shells

Comment: Sounds interesting, but can it attach to something that wasn't originally started in one of its sessions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GDB to attach a running process to a terminal.

Here's a description spread across several answers to a question (particularly see the one by Mirek):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593724/redirect-stderr-stdout-of-a-process-after-its-been-started-using-command-line

Answer (score -1):

No way to do that. Just kill the detached process. If you want to do this intentionally, have a look at the 'screen' command. This will not save you if your underlying shell dies though.